# How to check malicious path against a root directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I want to join two paths:

```
var path = require('path');
path.join(root, requestPath);
```

How to prevent path like `../../../../../etc/passwd`? What's the best practice?

```
var isMalicious = function(path, root) { /* HOW TO */ };
```

Comment: Change the permissions of ../etc/passwd to make it inaccessible?

Comment: Use some path utility to resolve the given path with `root` as prefix to its absolute representation (I guess that’s what `path.join` already does). Then check if it’s still within `root`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what Gumbo said. Here is a code sample:

```
var path = require('path');
var root = '/var/www/app/';

var path = require('path');
var filename = path.join(root, requestPath);

if (filename.indexOf(root) !== 0) {
  //  someone is trying to break out of root!
}
```

This is worth reading for more security issues. [How can I secure my code?](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/security/introduction)

Comment: Make sure the `root` ends with `/`.